# Why are httpd processes spending increasing amounts of time in logging state?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, performance-tuning

I'm running an Apache 2.2 web server.

When stress testing I notice that I cannot increase load beyond a certain number of simultaneous connections.
The strange thing is that I do not seem to have reached the limit of CPU or memory, and I hardly see any increase in page serve time.

What I notice, however, is that an increasing proportion of httpd processes are in what mod_status calls the "Logging" state:

[image: Concurrent httpd processes by State]

*MaxClients is 500 but as you can see, the actual number of processes that are available to handle a connection decreases as more and more processes spend their time logging.*

**How can this be?**

My first guess would be a disk IO bottleneck, but a few things speak against it:

1. There's no bottleneck in other parts of the application though even more disk IO should be going on elsewhere.
2. Each process should only write one line to the access log at the end of the request. If there's a bottleneck here, disk writes are unusually slow by today's standards.

**What can I do to investigate this further?**

Thanks,
Jakob

Comment: I'm very suspicious of your assertion that there is no I/O bottleneck. If the other I/O is O_DIRECT then it won't be affected by cache starvation. If the other I/O is writing to a different part of the disk then it won't be affected by localized surface errors.

Comment: Ok, @symcbean, how would you go about confirming that there's waiting time writing to the apache access log?

Comment: Way too broad too answer here - but the first things I'd be looking at are load, iostat,  processes in uninterruptible sleep, playing with the /proc/sys/vm/dirty* files...